# Understanding the Ising Model and finding the MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, graphical-model, markov-random-field

In a binary pairwise MRF, the joint distribution is as follows:

\begin{align}
p(x\mid\theta) & = \exp\left(\sum_{s \in N} \theta_s x_s + \sum_{(s,t) \in E} \theta_{st} x_s x_t - \Phi(\theta)\right) \\ \Phi(\theta) & = \log\left(\sum_{x}\exp\left( \sum_{s \in N} \theta_s x_s + \sum_{(s,t) \in E} \theta_{st} x_s x_t \right) \right)
\end{align}

$$x_s^{(\ell)} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if person $s$ votes yes on matter $\ell$}, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

I've heard that this graph is something called Ising model from statistical physics. However, I'm not sure how to interpret this/estimate values.

Say that I want to take the MLE of $\theta_s$, and I have a disconnected graph ($E = \emptyset$), how would I find a closed-form expression?

Comment: Simply express the above when $E=\emptyset$. The notation is confusing, though: is $\theta_s$ indexed/varying with $s$ in which case you have one parameter by binary variate or constant in $s$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a generic graph, finding that MLE is a hard task, you will most likely need to resort to some approximation. In the literature you can find this referred to as the *Inverse Ising problem*.

If the graph is disconnected, you are left with a set of independent binary random variables, for which the MLE estimator is straightforward to compute. You should get
$$\theta_s^{MLE}=\log\frac{\mu_s}{1-\mu_s}$$
where
$$\mu_s=\frac1L\sum_{l=1}^Lx_s^{(l)}$$